# Save popup message is frequently shown in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, disablers

I have added values in few fields across 400+ items in the Sitecore programmatically.

After creating all the items in the Sitecore `master` database, I am getting this message when I click on each one of them:

> Do you want to save the changes to the item?

I published all the items and the items whatever updated programmatically is reflected in the Sitecore `web` database also.

I have used `SecurityDisabler` when modifying the items in Sitecore.

We are using `Sitecore 9`.

Questions:

1. What could be the reason for this save popup?
2. Has anyone come across this issue?

Comment: Have you call the method `EndEdit()` after adding the values?

Comment: yes i used EndEdit method.

Comment: Strongly disagree with closing this question. I myself had similar issue it turned out adblockers where the culprits.

Answer (score 0):

Does your new field values perhaps contain new lines \n or carriage returns \r ?

This can cause your browser to pick these up as being different to what is in Sitecore.

if so you could try replacing them with spaces or empty strings:

```
public static string CleanNewLinesTabsAndOtherStuff(this string s)
{
  return s.Replace("\r\n", " ").Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ").Replace("\t", " ").Replace('\xA0', '\x20');
}
```

Take a look at Brian Pedersens blog post on this here for more info:

https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/11/30/sitecore-save-dialog-appears-for-unchanged-content/amp/

If this isn’t your issue could it potentially be related to versions of items, there is a known bug for this message with regard to version management in 8.1, I’m not sure if it exists in 9 still.

https://community.sitecore.net/general/f/16/t/2285

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i already had a look at Brian's post. I couldn't see any new lines or carriage returns in the values which i have updated.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Did you look into if the Sitecore Hotfix: 76398 is the issue as per the link at the end of my reply?

Comment: Adam, After complete republish of website, i couldn't see that popup message anymore. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @arjunan glad you managed to sort it anyway.